# Can Look-up Array be Stored Outside Class?

Tags: php, oop

I'm just starting to learn about OOP and am converting a small existing site in the process. I have a large global array ($countries) where I store the country code, name in two different languages, and international calling code for about 240 countries. I want to create a class (Country) with methods which would look up values from $countries. Do I need to store the array inside the class, or can I store it in a separate file? If I can put it in a separate file, how would I access it in my methods?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, return the array from that file, and then use it like:

```
$array = include('file.php')
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php

**file.php**

```
<?php

return array(
'name' => 'Josh Smith'
);
```

**index.php**

```
<?php

$arr = include('file.php');
var_dump($arr);
```

**Class Whatever**

```
class Whatever {


    public function getCountries() {

        $arr = include('file.php');
        return $arr;

    }

}


$what = new Whatever();
$c = $what->getCountries();
var_dump($c);
```

Comment: Would I do that inside the class or in the file calling the class?

Comment: You can do that where ever you want the array. Probably, if you are using OOP, you would have a method that would perform such functionality, and you can ->getCountries() with relative ease from your object instance.

Comment: So I would include the file inside the getCountries() method?

Comment: Yes, this separation of concerns will mean if your code changes in the future, you wouldn't have to change file names in multiple places. You amend that particular function. I think, at first, try out my method in the answer, and then turn it OOP later.

Comment: Yes, that is how I'm currently doing it. The point is I'm trying to convert it to OOP. This is my first class, so I wasn't sure if I could include files inside classes and/or methods.

Answer (score 1):

You should definitely store the list of countries outside of your class code to avoid source code changes every time you need to update a list. Depends on your use-case it could be a file or a database table.

Your look-up class should get information where to load data from while it is constructed.

Something like this:

```
class CountryProvider {

    protected $countries = [];

    public function __construct($dataFile)
    {
        $this->loadDataFromFile($dataFile);
    }

    protected function loadDataFromFile($dataFile)
    {
        // load your file here into $countries property
    }

    public function findCountryByCode($code)
    {
        // do your lookup here
    }
}

$countryProvider = new CountryProvider('/path/to/your/file');
$country = $countryProvider->findCountryByCode('SOME_COUNTRY_CODE');
```

Comment: This is my first class, so I'm not sure what you mean. How would I do that?